# Ruby on Rails RSpec put method doesn't see signed in user

Tags: ruby, authentication, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

so I've been using Michael Hartl's tutorial for some time and I can say it's really useful but there's a problem and I gues it's not on the tutorial's part. So in chapter "9.2.2 Requiring the right user" ther's a test for checking that a user can access neither other user's edit page nor submit a direct PUT reauest.

```
describe "as wrong user" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
  before { sign_in user }

  describe "visiting Users#edit page" do
    before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
    it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
  end

  describe "submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action" do
    before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
  end
end
```

So long all seems right but the test fails:

```
1) Authentication authorization as wrong user submitting a PUT request to the Users#update action ←[31mFailure/Error:←[0m ←[31mspecify { response.should redirect_to(root_path }←[0m←[31mExpected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/signin>←[0m←[36m # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:107:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'←[0m
```

Here's the User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
@user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    sign_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
end

def update
  if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    sign_in @user
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      puts "No user signed in"
    store_location
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  puts "Incorrect user" unless current_user?(@user)
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
  end
end
```

So as you can see the problem is that when using RSpec put method, the test fails even before checking for the right user because it sees ther's no user signed in.
This is a small problem which can easily be omitted (incorrect user cannot make direct PUT request anyway) but it's a puzzle for me why doesn't it work correct and I can't get the answer for quite a time already.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `signed_in_user` filter is redirecting back to the sign in page before the `correct_user` fires. That suggests that the user is not actually signed in correctly by the `sign_in user` call in the before block.

Have you defined sign_in in `spec/support/utilities.rb`?

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
  visit signin_path
  fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  fill_in "Password", with: user.password
  click_button "Sign in"
  # Sign in when not using Capybara as well.
  cookies[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve, but sign_in was already defined so it seems that it's not the case.

Comment: Looks like its failing to log in though. You could try calling `save_and_open_form` from your test to see if there are any error messages on the page. Alternatively, are there any clues in  log/test.log?